# Q not chaining properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I try to chain promises. Below getExternalMap() is returning a promise (process an ajax call => deferred.resolve() and return deferred.promise). "First chaining" is called without problem but "Second chaining" is not called, any idea why ?

I thought it was well written but it's not and I can't find why yet.

```
var self = this;
getExternalMap().then(function() {
        console.log("First chaining");
        var parsedMap = self.destinationsApiParser.getSortDestinations();
        return self.initProxies(parsedMap);
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('second chaining');
    });

this.initProxies = function(parsedMap) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var destinationsApiProxy = new DestinationsApiProxy(this.app, parsedMap);
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: add a `catch()` or `done()` to the end of the chain to see any errors.

Comment: `initProxies` should not return a promise. It is not asynchronous.

Comment: found the problem thanks to sirko, initProxies was doing shit and kinda crashed silently. Also Bergi's remark is good too. thank you to both of you

Comment: @Bergi but will it chain properly if I don't return a promise ? even if it's synchronous ?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard: Yes. `then` is magic, it detects whether you return a promise (and awaits it) or not (and resolves immediately).

Comment: `process.on("unhandledRejection", e => { throw e; })` should flush the error. That works for Q for over a year.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to do this instead:

```
var self = this;
getExternalMap()
    .then(() => console.log("1st chaining"))
    .then(self.destinationsAPIParser.getSortDestinations)
    .then(self.initProxies)
    .then(() => console.log("2nd chaining"))

this.initProxies = function(parsedMap) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var destinationsApiProxy = new DestinationsApiProxy(this.app, parsedMap);
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Assuming that `self.destinationsAPIParser.getSortDestinations` returns a promise.